# How do I create a surface plot with 4 datasets of vectors?

Tags: matlab

I would like to generate a surface plot like so:
[image]

I already have 3 different data sets for β (for β = 15, 20, 30), and each of these values for β have corresponding λ and Cp vectors, as seen here (the different colours signify different β values).

[image]

How would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a mesh grid to cover all the X,Y dimensions then evaluate your B[20,30,50] accordingly you should be able to get your plot as an example

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1.5:0.01:3.5,0.05:0.01:.45);

[m,n]=size(X);
for i=1:m
 for j=1:n
  if X(i,j)<2.1
    BB(i,j)=X(i,j)^2+Y(i,j); %B20
  elseif X(i,j)<2.7
     BB(i,j)=X(i,j)+Y(i,j)^2; %B30
  else
     BB(i,j)=X(i,j)-Y(i,j); %B50
  end
end
end
figure
surface(X,Y,BB);
grid on
view(3)
```